# Save Frames from Video OpenCV-python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to save frames from a video. My problem is that saved frames keep overwriting and only last frame saved at the end.
Here is my code

```
import cv2

vc = cv2.VideoCapture('111.mp4')
c = 1
if vc.isOpened():
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False
timeF = 30
while rval:
    rval, frame = vc.read()
    if not rval: break
    if (c % timeF == 0):
        cv2.imwrite('/home/benson/Image/imagename.jpg', frame)
    c = c + 1
    cv2.waitKey(1)
vc.release()
```

Comment: outside while loop initiate an empty list, for example frames = []. Then inside the while loop append frames with frame in each cycle: frames.append(frame)

Answer (score 0):

You already have a counter available, why aren't you using it?

```
cv2.imwrite('/home/benson/Image/imagename_{:04d}.jpg'.format(c), frame)
```

Good luck

Andreas